# Google Search Results: sub-page description

Tags: seo, wordpress, google-search, meta-tags

I have a Wordpress site that successfully has 6 sub-pages listed below the main result in Google. However a page content snippet is showing up or each instead of the sub-page meta descriptions.

I have verified in the page source that the meta descriptions are being successfully inserted by my SEO plugin.

How can I define the sub-page descriptions?

Comment: you can't, google can pick and choose, even modify the descriptions show to better match what has been searched.